# lilo: disable second disk /dev/sdb

Tags: kernel, boot, disk, lilo

is it possible to use `append="something"` in `/etc/lilo.conf` to disable completely secondary disk ?

The disk `/dev/sdb` reports errors, and it takes a long time to boot.

I would like the disk to be ignored completely, without having to physically remove it.

Comment: Out of curiosity why do you use lilo when grub is infinitely better?

Comment: @AH, LILO is simpler and grub being better is an opinion.

Comment: Check this SU Q/A: https://superuser.com/questions/599333/how-to-disable-kernel-probing-for-drive